# Where is clipboard data located in Windows 10 if we have enabled Clipboard History?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

I have captured multiple screen snippets using Win + Shift + S and they are all stored in clipboard as I have enabled "Clipboard History." Now is there any place on hard drive where all those images are stored? Because saving them manually is laboursome. I'll have to paste them one by one in paint or some other image editor and save them individually.

Comment: That is Snip and Sketch.  Default folder is here:  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch  .   That is a heavily secured folder and I suggest you use Save as to put the files where you want. Snagit (the grown up product) stores its files in Documents

Comment: @John that should be an answer if correct.

Comment: @Moab I just checked the app. It is only responsible for making the screen shot and saving it into the clipboard. Hence no disk access as everything is just in RAM. The Clipboard history however seems to be independent of that app (a second app?).

Answer (score 1):

@Ahmad - Moab has suggested I post this as an answer and I hope you find it useful

That is Snip and Sketch. Default folder is here: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch . That is a heavily secured folder and I suggest you use Save as to put the files where you want. Snagit (the grown up product) stores its files in Documents

I encourage you to use your own folder (as I do) for your own convenience.

Comment: That is the path where the app binaries are installed but I doubt that the user data is stored there too (and that was the question if I got it correctly).

Comment: I did check in Documents and other common user areas when Snip and Sketch might store this and no - not there.  Having your own location is definitely best

Comment: @John you might explain how to use your own folder.

Comment: For this purpose, I use a folder on Documents. My folder is called SnagIt (because that is my capture app) . You could call it SnipSketch as a folder in Documents

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch is unavailable to me because  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps is restricted.

My workaround is, for every copy action, additionally paste to Word.

Clipboard History become important when restart is needed for loss of data due to Microsoft App freezing; however, it

1. 25 items can't suffice heavy copy paste between Apps
2. cleared after Restart of Computer in my computer config
3. Blanks occur for unknown reason

Unsure why Clipboard folder is hidden but its accessibility greatly alleviate above labour. 3rd Party App is not a option in my case.